# How can I pushd a series of directories in one go?

Tags: bash, pipe, xargs, pushd

I am in the directory `foo` which contains the subdirectories `bar1` `bar2` and `bar3` and nothing else.

I would like to act `pushd` on `foo`, `bar1`, `bar2` and `bar3` in one command, however I am encountering difficulties:

```
find `pwd` | xargs pushd
```

returns

```
xargs: pushd: No such file or directory
```

I tried to circumvent the problem with a while loop:

```
find `pwd` | while read line ; do pushd $line ; done
```

Which gives an output which looks correct:

```
~/foo ~/foo
~/foo/bar1 ~/foo ~/foo
~/foo/bar2 ~/foo/bar1 ~/foo ~/foo
~/foo/bar3 ~/foo/bar2 ~/foo/bar1 ~/foo ~/foo
```

However using `dirs` after that shows that I have not added any new directories to the stack:

```
~/foo
```

Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re very close. 
You can do what you want with

```
while read line; do pushd "$line"; done < <(find "$(pwd)" -type d)
```

The problem with your command is that `pushd`, like `cd`,
must be done in the main (parent) process to be useful,
and (with some variation based on how your system is set up),
the commands in a pipeline run in subprocesses (child processes). 
`< <(cmd)` magically gives you a pipe
without giving you a pipeline.

This requires that you are running bash
(or maybe one of the other advanced shells?),
since POSIX doesn’t support `<(cmd)`.

The `xargs` approach, sadly, was doomed to failure,
because `pushd` (like `cd`) is a shell builtin command
(i.e., there is no *program* called `pushd`),
and `xargs` requires an external, executable program. 
You can get output that (almost) looks right with this command:

```
$ find "$(pwd)" -type d | xargs -i sh -c 'pushd "$1"' sh
~/foo ~/foo
~/foo/bar1 ~/foo
~/foo/bar2 ~/foo
~/foo/bar3 ~/foo
```

but that is executing the shell as an external program,
and doing so (independently) for each directory. 
This is a little closer:

```
$ find "$(pwd)" -type d | xargs sh -c 'for line do pushd "$line"; done' sh
~/foo ~/foo
~/foo/bar1 ~/foo ~/foo
~/foo/bar2 ~/foo/bar1 ~/foo ~/foo
~/foo/bar3 ~/foo/bar2 ~/foo/bar1 ~/foo ~/foo
```

executing a single shell process,
and telling it to loop over all the directories. 
As you can see,
this technique is similar to your second attempt (and my answer),
and the result is the same as your second attempt —
you get a new shell process that calls `pushd` four times,
and ends up with a directory stack that is five levels deep
(counting the starting directory twice) —
but that new shell process is in a subprocess, 
and, by the time you see the next shell prompt, *that* shell process is gone.

For reference, note that this command is somewhat similar to
[an answer I gave a couple of years ago](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/203867/80216#203967). 
[Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%c3%a9phane-chazelas) discusses
the `sh -c long_complex_shell_command sh` command construct
[here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/93324/80216#93331) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/156008/80216#156010).

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! Any idea what was wrong with the xargs syntax besides the pipe?

Comment: Because xargs wants a command to run, and pushd is a shell built-in.

Comment: @Miguel: I have updated my answer to address that.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a job for `find`.

```
for subdirectory in */; do
  pushd -- "$subdirectory"
done
```

Your code doesn't work because `pushd`, like `cd`, needs to execute in the shell environment that you want to affect. There is no external command `pushd` that `xargs` could call because an external command would be pointless: it would not affect anything. The right-hand side of a pipe runs in a subshell (in your shell, there are shells where it runs in your other shell and your second attempt would work); you can see `pushd` working with

```
find `pwd` | {
  while read line ; do pushd $line ; done;
  dirs
}
```

Working unless the directory names contain special characters, that is. [Always put double quotes around variable substitutions unless you know why you need to leave them off](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters).

Comment: It would be neat if `DIRSTACK+=( */ )` worked, but you can only modify existing entries in `DIRSTACK[]`, not add (or remove) :-/